# Convert Java Object into a XML String using jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I would like to convert a Java Object to a String containing the marshaled XML data. One of the ways I could find was to first marshal to a File and then read the file using BufferedReader to convert into a String. I feel this may not be the most efficient way, because the IO operations are performed twice (Once during marshaling and the second time during the conversion of file content into String)

Could anyone please suggest any better approach?

Answer (score 8):

Pass a StringWriter object as argument to [marshal method](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Writer%29) of Marshaller

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Account account = N.fill(Account.class);
String xml = N.toXML(account);
N.println(xml); // <account><id>6264304841028291043</id><gui>33acdcbe-fd5b-49</gui><emailAddress>19c1400a-97ae-43</emailAddress><firstName>67922557-8bb4-47</firstName><middleName>7ef242c9-8ddf-48</middleName><lastName>1ec6c731-a3fd-42</lastName><birthDate>1480444055841</birthDate><status>1444930636</status><lastUpdateTime>1480444055841</lastUpdateTime><createTime>1480444055841</createTime></account>
Account account2 = N.fromXML(Account.class, xml);
assertEquals(account, account2);
```

Declaration： I'm the developer of abacus-common.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Simplicity: It's easy to serialize an java Object to String/File/OuputStream/Writer or deserialize from String/File/InputStream/Reader. please refer to the Java API docs Parser[http://www.landawn.com/api-docs/com/landawn/abacus/parser/Parser.html]: in above

Comment: Performance: it's about 3 to 10+ times faster than JAXB provided in JDK and XStream, depending on the size of xml/Java Object. and about 20% faster thank Jackson XML. i will update the comments about performance in the answer.